# How Do I Increment a Local Variable from Inside a Helper

Tags: c#, razor

I am attempting to keep count of total times my `@helper` is ran (to breakup the list items this `@helper` outputs into sets of 10).

For whatever reason, I cannot find/figure this out. I simply need a variable that I can increment from within a `@helper`.

```
@functions
{
    public int totalItems = 0;
}

@helper myHelper()
{
    @if (totalItems % 10 == 0)
    {
        </ul><ul>
    }

    <li>List Item #@totalItems</li>

    @{
        // Increment counter
        totalItems = (totalItems + 1);
    }
}

@{
    <ul>
        @for(var i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            @myHelper();
        }
    </ul>

    // It would be great if I could do this after the loop!
    <p>Last list contains @totalItems list items!</p>
}
```

I just brain-dumped the code above, so sorry if there are syntax errors... But I think it gets my point across?

I want the above code to output:

```
<ul>
    <li>List Item #1</li>
    <li>List Item #2</li>
    <li>List Item #3</li>
    <li>List Item #4</li>
    <li>List Item #5</li>
    <li>List Item #6</li>
    <li>List Item #7</li>
    <li>List Item #8</li>
    <li>List Item #9</li>
    <li>List Item #10</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>List Item #1</li>
    <li>List Item #2</li>
    <li>List Item #3</li>
    <li>List Item #4</li>
    <li>List Item #5</li>
    <li>List Item #6</li>
    <li>List Item #7</li>
    <li>List Item #8</li>
    <li>List Item #9</li>
    <li>List Item #10</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li>List Item #1</li>
    <li>List Item #2</li>
    <li>List Item #3</li>
    <li>List Item #4</li>
    <li>List Item #5</li>
</ul>
```

The aforementioned markup does not achieve this though. Instead, the page errors. I am not using an IDE like Visual Studio, so I do not know what error is being thrown, but the error occurs when I add the following to my View:

```
@{
    // Increment counter
    totalItems = (totalItems + 1);
}
```

Can anyone explain the right way to achieve this? Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Take the `totalItems` variable out of a `@functions` block and just into a `@{...}` block or it will go out of scope.

Comment: You are resetting your `totalItems` back to 0 every time it gets to 10. Instead of resetting it try `if(totalItems % 10 == 0)` to check that the modulo (remainder) is 0,

Comment: @DavidG - If I do that, then I must pass `totalItems` into the `@helper` as an argument, right?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but I don't think so

Comment: @gmiley - Yeah, that probably wasn't a good interpretation of what I want to do. I'll remove the reset to 0...

Comment: @DavidG - I will try it that way, but I think that was the first thing I tried...

Comment: @DavidG - Yeah, The page errors when I don't pass the variable as an argument :(

Answer (score 0):

You could probably simplify the whole thing like this:

```
@helper myHelper(){
    int totalItems = 0;
    <ul>
        @for(var i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        {
            totalItems = i;
            @if (totalItems % 10 == 0)
            {
                </ul><ul>
            }
            <li>List Item #@totalItems</li>
        }
    </ul>

    <p>Last list contains @totalItems list items!</p>
}
```

By getting rid of all of the extra `helper` stuff, and using modulo (`%`) instead of resetting at every 10 count. You may need to make some modifications, I am not very familiar with razor syntax.

Comment: I am working with a framework that uses a helper to output the navigation. This is the helper I am trying to modify. What you have provided works, just not from inside of my helper. Can you revise using a helper?

Comment: Here is the View I am working with: https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/blob/master/src/Presentation/Nop.Web/Views/Catalog/TopMenu.cshtml

Comment: Please see `@helper RenderCategoryLine()`

Comment: Well, I updated, but as I said, I am not very familiar with the razor syntax so you may need to refine it more on your own. The idea is to combine all of the related stuff together and not reset your counter variable.

Comment: For sure, I will see if I can rework this to increment a variable defined in the helper. Not sure if it is doable as the helper is called multiple times (different `<ul>`'s). Thank you very much for your answer. Great stuff!